# Adding multiple children to a property of a custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, itemscontrol

I am trying to create a base view that knows where to place some buttons (Actions) that I am defining in my actual views. I have `ViewA` which derives from `BaseView`. `BaseView` is a custom control with some properties and a generic template. `ViewA` derives from `BaseView` and defines some buttons that `BaseView` should display in a `StackPanel`.

This is how `ViewA` should look:

```
<BaseView x:Class="ViewA"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <!-- This will be the main content for the view -->
    </Grid>
    <BaseView.Actions>
        <!-- Here I want these buttons to be displayed in a StackPanel where the template is defined by BaseView -->
        <Button>Button1</Button>
        <Button>Button2</Button>
    </BaseView.Actions>
</BaseView>
```

This is my BaseView template with where I would like the buttons to be displayed:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type BaseView}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type BaseView}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" />
                        <!-- I would like the buttons defined in Actions to display here in a StackPanel -->
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

How can I accomplish this? I was trying to use an `ItemsControl` but I am unsure what type the "Actions" property should be and how to bind that to an `ItemsControl`?

Comment: I forgot to mention that BaseView derives from ContentControl which allows the ContentPresenter to display the main content defined in ViewA.

Comment: I see you have a `BaseView.Actions` property. Is it a collection of `Button`s? You should re-think your approach and use the MVVM way in WPF: view-models, data binding, and data temlating. MVVM allows you to easily build rich user interfaces and additionally encourages you to separate your view layer from the business logic layer. However, this would be too much to explain in one answer...

Comment: @dymanoid `BaseView.Actions` is just pseudo-code to show how I want to define my "Actions" in the view. I am using MVVM in my application but I want to define the action controls in the XAML since it is to do with the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up implementing this with the below dependency property and an ItemsControl in my template:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ActionsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Actions", typeof(ObservableCollection<UIElement>), typeof(ModalWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<UIElement>()));

public ObservableCollection<UIElement> Actions
{
    get => (ObservableCollection<UIElement>)GetValue(ActionsProperty);
    set => SetValue(ActionsProperty, value);
}
```

---

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Actions}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

---

Usage:

```
<BaseView.Actions>
    <Button>Action 1</Button>
    <Button>Action 2</Button>
</BaseView.Actions>
```

I think a `UIElementCollection` would have been better suited for the type of the property but I am unsure how to instantiate that collection with the required parameters.